# Having trouble extracting inner text of <td> tags in beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am using bs4 to scrape a website with a list of years.

```
years = soup.find_all('td', class_='EndCellSpacer')
```

which returns an array of matching tags:

```
[<td class="EndCellSpacer">
                        2014
                </td>, <td class="EndCellSpacer">
                        2015
                </td>, <td class="EndCellSpacer">
                        2016
                </td>, <td class="EndCellSpacer">
                        2017
                </td>, <td class="EndCellSpacer">
                        2018
                </td>, <td class="EndCellSpacer">
                        2019
                </td>, <td class="EndCellSpacer">
                        2020
                </td>, <td class="EndCellSpacer">
                        2021
                </td>]
```

I want the array to only return the years without the `<td>` tags. I have tried to use

```
years = soup.find_all('td', class_='EndCellSpacer').text.strip()
```

but I am getting this error message:

> "ResultSet object has no attribute 'text'. You're probably treating a
> list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when
> you meant to call find()?"

If I call `find()`, it only returns the year from the first `<td>` tag, and I need all of them.

This might have something to do with the values being in an array but I can't seem to figure it out. I would greatly appreciate the help, this is my first time working in Python :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the result of

```
soup.find_all('td', class_='EndCellSpacer')
```

it is a list, so you need to iterate over it and get the text of each `td` tag:

```
out = [td.get_text().strip() for td in soup.find_all('td', class_='EndCellSpacer')]
```

Output:

```
['2014', '2015', '2016', '2017', '2018', '2019', '2020', '2021']
```